# show detail steps of an Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I compared the results of an integration exercise, one was done by Mathematica Alpha, the other one was done by hand on my own. I'm sure MA is right, however I could not find out which step went wrong on my own calculation. Could anybody help? Can MA show the intermediate steps?
[image: Integration done by hand]
[image: Integration done by Mathematica Alpha]

Comment: Were you using W|A on mobile? This has steps for me: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+Sqrt%5Bsin(x)+-+sin(x)%5E3%5D+from+0+to+pi

Comment: Your mistake is assuming $\sqrt{1 - \sin^2(x)} = \cos(x)$, when it actually equals $|\cos(x)|$.

Comment: Followed your link, the result was more or less the same as I posted here. The question is how MA got the last Indefinite integral listed above, and the result should be zero if substitute Pi and 0 into it, not as the answer 1.33333 listed in the begining.

Comment: Here is the link I got the result listed above:http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=8ab70731b1553f17c11a3bbc87e0b605

Comment: Are you on mobile? In my browser (on my desktop) that link has a step-by-step button. The mobile app has step-by-step solutions.

Comment: Don't use a widget, they don't have step-by-step buttons. Use wolframalpha.com instead.

Comment: Oh, yes I only got the first two steps and "To see all the steps got Pro now." Do you mind post what you saw on your screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WolframAlpha["Integrate[Sqrt[Sin[x]-Sin[x]^3],{x,0,Pi}]", {{"Input", 
   2}, "Content"}, PodStates -> {"Input__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

[image]